# Redirect primary/root component from within a child component Angular2

Tags: redirect, angular, router

So, as I mentioned in one of my posts, I am using something like this https://gist.github.com/ShurikAg/3c8afc05765cf1b5941b3cc3f81523df to control authentication/authorization on redirects. And it works perfectly.

However, when I have nested route outlets, instead of redirecting the entire page to login page (when needed) the login page is rendered within that specific outlet where it restricted... as expected.

The question is, how do I redirect the root component to where I need to? **(answered below, unless it is wrong)**

Also, is there a way to know if from within the router directive, if this is a root or child router?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I answered myself the first question:

In provided gist (lines: 37-38) should be replaced with:

```
this.parentRouter.root.navigate([this.signin]);
```